# Most upvoted answers

Tags: support, answers, statistics, up-votes, data-explorer

How to get the list of top $N$ answers that have been upvoted the most?

For questions it is very easy, but not for answers.

I don't expect some hidden web page, but a database query would be perfect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The search parameter `is:answer` returns only answers, and you can sort this by votes: [search results](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aanswer). This worries about score, and not simply upvotes (so a hypothetical answer with a huge number of up- **and** down-votes is likely omitted). It also doesn't give you the "top $N$", but it does order them correctly.

You can also use the [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/revision/232763/304950/top-n-most-upvoted-answers), but the results here are not quite as "live" (the data is only updated on a weekly basis), though I don't expect huge changes in this list. (The linked query only counts upvotes, and ignores downvotes.)

Comment: Great!! This works for me. Score and upvotes are practically the same, for my case.